# One to many video Audio conferencing - webrtc - openTok

Tags: webrtc, broadcasting, video-conferencing, opentok

I searched about this on google but could not find any suitable answer so posting here for help.

I want to implement video streaming with multiple participants connected. While google this topic I found that `WebRTC` provide similar functionality but I want to make sure whether WebRTC can support all my requirements.

I want to build an application that should support large number of participants in conference (around 10000). 
I want to implement facility like one participant is broadcasting its video and audio streams and other are just listening to their stream.

Also when prompted only one participant will be able to communicate with broadcaster which will be managed by one participant (a administrator). Administrator will decide who can communicate with broadcaster.

Is same can be possible with any other WebAPI ?? I found `OpenTok`, but not confident if it provide any feature of moderation in conference (i.e. feature of having an Administrator who manages stuff)

Did anybody worked on similar concept or having any information related to this.

Let me know if I am not clear of any further details are required.
Any help would be useful,
Thanks in anticipation

Answer (score 2):

Hardik - I am Product Manager at TokBox, the makers of the OpenTok platform. Good news: TokBox can fulfill virtually all of your requirements, but with a few caveats.

TokBox has been building a video chat/conferencing platform for years, long before WebRTC even existed in fact. In that time we have supported many customers with almost your exact requirements on OpenTok, a platform that is based on Flash (Major League Baseball is one such customer). Building applications on this architecture has the added advantage of solving virtually all of the interop issues that exist when connecting people using different devices and browsers. It is based on Flash however, which technically doesn't meet your WebRTC requirement. So you know, there's that.

WebRTC is where it's at though, which is why we created OpenTok for WebRTC in 2012. It was a complete rewrite of the platform that not only provides higher quality video, but also gives developers more hooks and far more control over how exactly they integrate video and audio chat into their primary customer experience.

Currently in beta (as of this writing in June 2013) are two new components in our WebRTC infrastructure. The first we refer to as Mantis, which solves many of the challenges associated with hosting large multi-party calls. The other is Cloud Raptor, which gives developers access to a stream of events stemming from a WebRTC session, and through which developers can issue events and commands of their own. Raptor is what enables you for example to moderate calls, boot participants, and control whose audio and video streams are broadcast to all the other participants.

So, TokBox has what you need. In the short term we can help you get up and running using OpenTok pretty quickly. Then we can discuss with you how to get you onto OpenTok for WebRTC and into our Mantis and Raptor beta program.

Comment: Does OpenTok have facility such one person (Administrator) can manage who can talk to each other in conference and can change participants who can talk to each other (others are just mute) ??

Comment: Yup! You should check out OpenTok's newly released Cloud Raptor SDK. Part of its functionality include [Moderation controls that allow an application’s own business logic dictate who gets into a session, how many connections can be in a session, the rules of when to kick someone out of a session without having to expose any of this functionality in the client](http://www.tokbox.com/blog/introducing-cloud-raptor-sdk-robust-apps-made-easy/)

Comment: In the one to many scenario, can the stream be received in an html5 video ? or do you have to use the je api ?

I'm asking this to know if i can read/play the stream in a browser on ios. I know you can't yet publish from ios browsers (well bowser excluded), but can you play the stream ?